# Import csv from GCS to BigQuery slower with smaller file using bq command

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, command

I'm using command like:

`bq load --skip_leading_rows=1 --source_format=CSV --preserve_ascii_control_characters=true --allow_quoted_newlines=true dataset.test_middle  $gcspath`

The weird thing is, it tooks 20s to upload a 50GB csv and took 200s to upload a 3GB csv. Errr does anyone know why is that and how to speed it?

Thanks!!

Comment: It's not a matter of size, but of warmup. BigQuery must reserve slots, discover the schema, infer the type by reading the first dozens of line, create the table and schema, and then, start the ingestion, which is very fast!

Comment: Hi @HappyFreddie, Could you please check if this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62303290/whats-the-quickest-way-to-upload-a-large-csv-file-8gb-from-local-computer-to) is helpful to resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi @HappyFreddie, Could you confirm if the above comment helped you or not ?

Comment: Thanks @SushmaJeerahalli Unfortunately, I think they r u helpful.

Comment: O I meant they r not helpful... Typo sorry..

Comment: Hi @HappyFreddie, could you please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104292/ingest-csv-file-times-in-bq#:~:text=In%20doing%20tests%20with%20ingesting,8%20minutes%20the%20second%20time.) if it helps to resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi @SushmaJeerahalli, so many thanks to u but still no hmmm. I'm almost give up. Looks like there's no answer for this question. Maybe only the guys invent bq command knows...

Answer (score 0):

if you have low bandwidth, you will be physically limited.

It is recommended to gzip your file before sending it. Text file has an high compression rate (up to 100 times) and you can [ingest gzip files directly into BigQuery without unzipping them](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#loading_compressed_and_uncompressed_data).

Comment: I know that. They are all uncompressed already. But if it's low bandwidth, why is the 50gb gile faster than the 5gb file? I just want to know why and find if it can be fixed.